# Compiled slug size: 578.1M is too large (max is 500M)

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, heroku

I have been trying to install my python dependencies and it's accumulating to a size of 578 MB, not letting me push my files.

This is the first time I am trying to push python dependencies to my application. Hence cache clearing is not the expected answer

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you expect your slug to be that big? Are you depending on anything you don't actually need?

Comment: My state of art model requires its dependencies (Tensorflow 2.x, keras, numpy, pandas, scipy). This is my requirements.txt. My tensorflow 2.1.0 itself accumulated to 420 MB. I can't think of downgrading it to any 1.x version as there won't be any GPU support in that case

Comment: Then maybe you need to find a new host.

Comment: Yup, it seems that's the only possible workaround left. Anyways thanks, cheers !!

Comment: Instead of pushing directly to Heroku (`git push heroku master`), you can set up a docker image (check documentation for how to do this; happy to help) and push that to Heroku (`heroku container:push ...`, `heroku container:release ...`). This procedure is not subject to the size limit.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I will try that and update.

Answer (score 3):

You could deploy with Docker instead. Heroku does not impose a size restriction on Docker images. Here's documentation on how to set up a Dockerfile, and then push and release a container with Heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker